# Number of non-equivalent first order logic formulas of rank k with no free variables

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

What is the best known lower bound on the number of non-equivalent first-order logic formulas of rank k with no free variables? For concreteness, we can consider the vocabulary of finite graphs.

The upper bound by doing structural induction on the definition of quantifier rank gives a non-elementary function. Do we know a non-elementary lower bound?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "rank k"?

Comment: By quantifier rank I mean the nested depth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_rank